# problem with GUI Buttons calling functions that prompt user input within the GUI and then display Output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I cannot get the user input within the GUI

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import math
```

Comment: If someone could point me to the right direction, i would greatly appreciate it

Comment: You need to use Entry fields rather than input() if you want user input within the GUI

Comment: Also if you want three buttons in the same window, don't create multiple frame objects

Comment: put all your functions (def) before `window = Tk()` to make code more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create main frame with buttons `Rectangle`,`Triangle` and use `pack()` to show it.

I also create two frames with `Entry` but I don't use `pack()` to show it.

When I click `Rectangle` or `Triangle` then it runs function which uses `pack_forget()` to remove main frame from window, and it uses `.pack()` two show one of frame with `Entry`.

This frame has button `Calc` which uses your function to calculate result - but it gets values from Entry and it displays result in Label.

It has also button `Back` which removes this frame and it shows main frame again.

I use `current` to remember current visible frame.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import math

# ---

def change_frame(new_frame):
    global current
    # hide current frame
    current.pack_forget()

    # show new frame
    current = new_frame
    current.pack()

def show_main_frame():
    change_frame(main_frame)

def show_rectangle_frame():
    change_frame(rectangle_frame)

def show_triangle_frame():
    change_frame(triangle_frame)

# ---

def calc_rectangle():
    try:
        l = float(rectangle_entry1.get())
        w = float(rectangle_entry2.get())
        arear=(l * w)
        print(arear)
        rectangle_result['text'] = str(arear)
    except ValueError:
        pass

def calc_triangle():
    try:
        b = float(triangle_entry1.get())
        h = float(triangle_entry2.get())
        areat=(0.5* b * h )
        print(areat)
        triangle_result['text'] = str(areat)
    except ValueError:
        pass

#-----

window = Tk()
window.title("Area Calculator")
#window.geometry("290x120")

main_frame = Frame(window)
main_frame.pack()

button = Button(main_frame, text="Rectangle", command=show_rectangle_frame)
button.pack()

button = Button(main_frame, text="Triangle", command=show_triangle_frame)
button.pack()

current = main_frame

# --- frame without .pack() ---

rectangle_frame = Frame(window)

rectangle_result = Label(rectangle_frame, text="")
rectangle_result.pack()

l = Label(rectangle_frame, text="Enter Length:")
l.pack()

rectangle_entry1 = Entry(rectangle_frame)
rectangle_entry1.pack()

l = Label(rectangle_frame, text="Enter Width:")
l.pack()

rectangle_entry2 = Entry(rectangle_frame)
rectangle_entry2.pack()

b = Button(rectangle_frame, text="Calc", command=calc_rectangle)
b.pack()

b = Button(rectangle_frame, text="BACK", command=show_main_frame)
b.pack()

# --- frame without .pack() ---

triangle_frame = Frame(window)

triangle_result = Label(triangle_frame, text="")
triangle_result.pack()

l = Label(triangle_frame, text="Enter base:")
l.pack()

triangle_entry1 = Entry(triangle_frame)
triangle_entry1.pack()

l = Label(triangle_frame, text="Enter Height:")
l.pack()

triangle_entry2 = Entry(triangle_frame)
triangle_entry2.pack()

b = Button(triangle_frame, text="Calc", command=calc_triangle)
b.pack()

b = Button(triangle_frame, text="BACK", command=show_main_frame)
b.pack()

# ---

window.mainloop()
```

---

Using `lambda` you can do

```
command=lambda:change_frame(rectanlge_frame)
```

and then you don't need function `show_rectanlge_frame`

The same with second frame.

---

There is more complex version created by Bryan Oakley which uses classes `Page(Frame)` and sometimes you can see these classes in questions on Stackoverflow.